# Error installing python simple-crypt on RHEL 6

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, rhel6, python-simple-crypt

I get an error when I try to install the simple-crypt package on RHEL 6 (`pip3.6 install simple-crypt`). Error code below:

```
running build_ext
running build_configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-build-a43nvnvj/pycrypto':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-a43nvnvj/pycrypto/setup.py", line 456, in <module>
    core.setup(**kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-a43nvnvj/pycrypto/setup.py", line 251, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-a43nvnvj/pycrypto/setup.py", line 278, in run
    raise RuntimeError("autoconf error")
RuntimeError: autoconf error

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-a43nvnvj/pycrypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0i_6q6fm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-a43nvnvj/pycrypto/
```

From what I can tell, the issue is with GCC. When I try to install python-ldap I get a "gcc failed with exit status 1" error. Currently, the server I am working on is running gcc 4.4.7, so I am not sure if I need to update it or not. I have limited experience working with RHEL, so I'm not sure where to go from here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around I found that it was due to the /tmp directory which pip uses having the noexec flag. As a solution I did `mount -o remount,exec /tmp` and when I was done `mount -o remount,noexec /tmp` to revert it to its original settings. After removing the noexec flag the package installed just fine.